# Matrices as labels in xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

How can I use a matrix as label in the `xymatrix` environment?
I tried to nest matrices (naively) but it seems to be rather complicated.

```
\xymatrix{
A \ar[r]^{\xymatrix{f \\ g}} & B
}
```

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't; but you can use `\substack`, provided by `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
A \ar[r]^{\substack{f \\ g}} & B
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative is the `smallmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
A \ar[r]^{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]} & B  
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user15412 Another possibility is to say `\ar[r]^{f}_{g}`